# Auto clicks on google ads wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a javascript/jQuery script that's auto click on the Google Adsense ads when the user visits the page.

```
<div class="samBannerUnit samAlignCenter" data-position="container_breadcrumb_top_above">
<div class="samItem"><a href="https://www.jmia.to/?fc" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><br>
```

here is an HTML of ads

Comment: <div class="samBannerUnit samAlignCenter" data-position="container_breadcrumb_top_above">
<div class="samItem"><a href="https://www.jmia.to/?fc" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><br>
<img src="https://www.jmia.to/banner/a.gif" alt=""></a></div>
</div>

Comment: This is contrary to Google Adword's rules of conduct and also an inefficient way to trick the user in clicking on an unwanted ad. Even if you do succeed, your payout from Google Adwords won't increase because they actually have a validation for the click. It needs to come from the user and not programatically.

Comment: this is immoral

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Haven't tested, but maybe something like this would work.

```
<script>
    function clickAd() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("samItem")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
    }

    window.onload = clickAd;
</script>
```

Comment: is there any lib file required?

Comment: I had to spend to much time on it, I had found some result but all of those are not working but from where I found those result people says its working, I think I have missed any lib aur other things.

Comment: Awesome sir , it's working but I have a dot can you define me "getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
why you add this and what is a purpose of it?

Comment: We need to catch exactly the element we want to click. 
From `document` we get children elements that have `samItem` -  this is the div in which our <a> tag resides.
Then we `getElementsByTagName` - actually child tags `a` of the div. 
Once we identified it - we click on it.
You may try executing it in portions in browser (F12 - DevTools - Console) to see what is returned on every step.
BTW, if you like answer, please mark it as correct. :)

Comment: One more thing ,the ad is open in the form of popup ,is there any way to open ad in same tab?

Comment: If not the ads open in other fourm ,because when scripts open the ads  ,the browser block ads and left the msg popup blocked

Comment: In your google ad code, `a` tag has `target="_blank"`:
<a href="jmia.to/?fc" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">
This causes opening in new tab/window.
You may try to override it by changing target to `_self` - change body of the function:

function clickAd() {
  var aTag = document.getElementsByClassName("samItem")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
  aTag.setAttribute('target', '_self');
  aTag.click();
}

Comment: can you do same thing for me last time please....... <script async
scr="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></Script>
<!-- header as -->
<ins class=""adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-8346343888412028"
data-ad-slot="6352727611"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || [].push({});

Comment: in this particular case there is no obvious `<a>` tag with link. To see the html structure you may right-click on their ad link in browser and select `Inspect` in menu. Then, on `Elements` tab you will see `<a>` or `<button>` tag with the link and will be able to use the same approach, as we done above.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you made my day

Comment: <div id="atContainer-bf41594e41768475c9a189f7b9e3d2e2">     <a id="atLink-bf41594e41768475c9a189f7b9e3d2e2" href="http://monstersclash.com/?utm_campaign=terra_bnr&amp;utm_medium=click&amp;utm_source=bn&amp;utm_content=fill" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="" src="https://cdn15a.acloudimages.com/512/d31/6d5/mc_na_09.07.2018_7280x900_13_en.gif" width="728" height="90"></a>

Comment: i;m back again ,i tried but its not getting solve <script>
    function clickAd() {
        document.getElementById("atLink-bf41594e41768475c9a189f7b9e3d2e2")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
    }

    window.onload = clickAd;
</script>

Comment: getElemetById returns only one value, not an array. So you don;t need to take [0] after it. Please try <script> function clickAd() { document.getElementById("atLink-bf41594e41768475c9a189f7b9e3d2e2").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click(); } window.onload = clickAd; </script>

Comment: this is popuder code <script type='text/javascript' src='//aggressiveracketscout.com/7a/ea/04/7aea04781ebac41f6b9d146744ae57bb.js'></script>  how to change tag open and close lik e <script> src='//aggressiveracketscout.com/7a/ea/04/7aea04781ebac41f6b9d146744ae57bb.js'></script>

Comment: accuallty i have to add popup ad script """"" <script type='text/javascript' src='//aggressiveracketscout.com/7a/ea/04/7aea04781ebac41f6b9d146744ae57bb.js'></script> """""into the button. how i can add them ,i mans to say when i press the button then script excute owtherwise not